# Watir webdriver: new window hiding behind main window

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, watir-webdriver

I've been doing some dabbling with test automation using Ruby and Watir webdriver...
I am running into an oddity where I open a new window, but when I act upon it, it performs all my actions *behind* the parent window
Here's how I set it up (using Firefox if that makes a difference):

```
# opens new window
b.button(:text => 'Upload').click
b.window(:url => 'urlname'). use do
    # action performed on the new window
    b.select_list(:id => 'selector').select 'Foo'
end
```

Note: it correctly performs actions on the select list present, but it does this *behind* the main browser.
Is there something specific I need to write in order for it to remain in front of the main window?

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If not, do you have any details to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
b.window(:url => 'urlname').focus
```

Put that line just after your `.use` line, and you should see the new window called to the foreground. You may actually find that you don't end up needing the `.use` line (or the `do/end`) at all.

Comment: sorry I didn't get back to you.  Yes, this resolved my issue, thanks!